# Когда писать фамилию впереди имени, а когда наоборот

Tags: стилистика, ономастика

Я журналист и в моей работе всегда приходится следить за тем, чтобы в подписях статей всегда имя шло впереди фамилии (Степан Иванов). Насколько я смутно помню, когда речь идет о живых людях, всегда пишется так, а если об умерших — наоборот (Иванов Степан). У нас с подругой даже возник спор — она всегда писала сначала фамилию, а потом имя и доказывала мне, что так правильно. Но никакой информации об этом в интернете не нашлось, чтобы доказать ей обратное. Есть ли вообще какое-то правило на этот счет?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Правила** на этот счёт нет и быть не может. Есть **рекомендация:** если не хотите, чтоб ваш текст отдавал мёртвой канцелярщиной, ставьте имя перед фамилией, это их естественный порядок. Разумеется, к официальным документам эта рекомендация не относится, а вот к газетам и журналам (как сказали бы чиновники, *к газетно-журнальной продукции*) — вполне. Что же касается «живых и мёртвых», то звучит это более чем странно. Похоже на байку или миф.